# Is there an English equivalent to "Presque vu"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, expression-choice

Is there an English equivalent to "[presque vu](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/presque_vu)": the feeling that something is on the tip of your tongue?

Usually, I hear "on the tip of my tongue", however, I am curious to
know if there are other English words meaning the same.

Comment: I know there's a word for that. I can almost see it in my mind.

Comment: Please can you edit your title to remove any use of French? This SE is for English.  Your query is much more suited to a translation forum such as can be found here http://forum.wordreference.com/forums/french-english-vocabulary-vocabulaire-fran%C3%A7ais-anglais.3/

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, I understand, but I am not requesting for translation. I got curious after reading a similar question on "this SE"- http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57690/english-equivalent-of-b%c3%aatise?s=3|1.4413

Comment: *Presque vu* is a loan term and English already.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I don't see why one should not refer to non-English words here, especially when trying to discover an English equivalent. Besides, English is not a language which exists in isolation from all other languages. It is merely one branch of the Indo-European family. And what happens in French is of relevance to English. Unless of course you think that God is an Englishman and therefore the language  has a special status in that regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like *déjà vu*, *presque vu* has been adopted into the English language (as you can see in the link you provided), although I imagine it is much less widely recognized than *déjà vu*.

So the English equivalent is simply ***presque vu***.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked Traxler's *Introduction to Psycholinguistics* where he calls them *tip-of-the-tongue experiences*, but he also refers to the phenomenon playfully in the title of the section as *access interruptus* (p. 45).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the newest common expression to describe the sudden, temporary disconnect of cognition and vocalization is **"brainfart"**. (AmE)

Comment: Oldbag:  Really?  That would seem to refer to using the wrong word, meaningless in the context, not to refer to being at a loss for a word.  I say "verbal logjam" when it happens to me.

Comment: @ab2 - I'm not particularly fond of it either - but, that's the way I've heard it used, and it's currently popular.